# Easiest manner to classify html vs. xml?

Tags: html, ruby, xml

After retrieving the body of a page from a link, what is the most efficient manner in which to verify whether the content is xml?

Currently I am testing the text for the regular expression `/xmlns/`, however with a sufficiently large dataset, I am sure this will lead to the occasional false positive. Does anyone know of a better approach to this issue?

I am using the Ruby programming language, if this makes any difference.

Comment: If an XML parser is able to parse it, it's XML

Comment: This would be rather time consuming though, won't it? I have to deal with approximately 150 000 documents every 30 mins..

Comment: What about XHTML? Or HTML that contains XML? How do you plan on handling those?

Comment: I only want pure xml documents. Everything else can be discarded.

Comment: XHTML is XML as well as HTML. Do you care or not?

Comment: No, I don't want XHTML either. I'm looking for rss/atom feeds, really. I am not aware of XHTML feeds, do they exist?

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but isn't it the responsibility of the of person who created the XML page to explicitly declare the content type? Are you writing a validator of some kind (e.g. to prove that a given page contains 100% valid XML)?

Comment: No, I am trying to extract XML feeds from a huge heap of web documents. There are a lot of poorly put together feeds, but I would still like to find as many as possible.

Comment: @providence - Why do you care if they are XML and not HTML? If the end goal is to be able to extract info from them, then why not just try to parse them and if you can't parse it, move on to the next one?

Comment: Data extraction is not really the goal at this point. I just need to separate xml feeds from all other web documents.

Comment: did you tried searching for `<?xml` at the start of the document ?

Comment: That's an interesting one, `/^<\?xml/` is less likely to false positive, I think. I'm playing around with JHolyhead's answer, I'll try a comparison of these two techniques. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML should start with `<?xml` or `<!DOCTYPE` ([but they don't have to](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-prolog), thanks to [Mike Sokolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914705/mike-sokolov) for the smack upside the head on this point :) so you might want to check for

```
/\A\s*(<\?xml|<!DOCTYPE)?/
```

to be forgiving.

Then, if the first element is

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

you have an [Atom feed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287).

If the first element is

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
```

(possibly with extra `xmlns` attributes) then you have an [RSS 1.0 feed](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/spec).

If the first element is

```
<rss version="2.0">
```

(again with possible `xmlns` attributes) then you have an [RSS 2.0 feed](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification).

You probably don't need to worry about the various 0.9* versions. So check for the XML header and then check for one of the three above elements (with possible extra attributes) with some loose regex wrangling something like this (untested and possibly too loose):

```
/\A\s*((<\?xml|<!DOCTYPE)[^>]*>\s*)?\<(feed|rdf:RDF|rss)/
```

and you'll be able to spot feeds without too much overhead.

You'd probably want to track what gets rejected for awhile and then run the rejects through a full parser to make sure you're not missing anything. Standards are often thought of as "rough suggestions" so you will encounter a lot of strange things out in the wild.

Comment: This is ideal. Thanks very much for the in depth explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but it's actually wrong - see my answer below; specifically the xml declaration is not required, and may be present in some html.

Comment: @Mike: Do you have a reference that the XML declaration is optional? Yes, it may be present in (X)HTML but that's why you check for the first element as a backup. Checking the Content-Type is a good idea but not very reliable in my experience.

Comment: actually I guess I didn't see anywhere that providence was interested in RSS as opposed to other kinds of XML?

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I should have been more clear in the original question. Your answer is more geared towards xml detection in general, which may serve useful in a later stage of my project.

Comment: @Mike: `XMLDecl?`, so yeah, it is optional and there's the possibility of `(doctypedecl Misc*)` as well; sigh, I thought XML was supposed to remove all the silly optional nonsense from SGML and HTML. The RSS stuff showed up in the comments "I just need to separate xml feeds from all other web documents."

Comment: @providence: I've updated the regexes a bit. You'd probably want to track what gets rejected for awhile and then run the rejects through a full parser to make sure you're not missing anything.

Comment: After a few days of experimentation, I have found that the regex should be tweaked slightly to: `/\A\s*((<\?xml|<!DOCTYPE)[^>]*>\s*)?\<(feed|rdf:RDF|rss|\?xml)/`. This helps with some feedburner feeds.

Answer (score 1):

If the document contains `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">`, it is likely an atom feed, alternatively, you could search for `</feed>`.

If the document contains `</rss>` it is likely an rss feed.

Regular expressions are your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to look at the HTTP Content-Type header.  This will most often be one of: text/html, text/xml, or text/xhtml, although in the wild anything goes, of course.

Examining the content, you should can look for an xml declaration if you want, but as this is not required for xml documents, and even if it is there, some html documents *are also* xml documents, so this won't tell you much.

Probably the best place to look in the content is the <DOCTYPE> declaration.  For html this will often read:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

but you will of course find many variations on that basic theme.

Another thing to look at is the root element of the document: if that has local-name="html"; ie it looks like  that is a very good sign you are dealing with html.

The presence of "xmlns" does not contra-indicate html; many html documents do include namespaces.  They are often generated as a standard part of an html document, and are required for using mathml and svg embedded in html.